# Django ORM: filter by multiple properties of related object

Tags: django

I have the following objects:

```py
class Image:
  user models.ForeignKey(User)
  corrupted = models.BooleanField()
  final = models.BooleanField()

class ImageRevision:
  image = models.ForeignKey(Image, related_name="revisions")
  corrupted = models.BooleanField()
  final = models.BooleanField()
```

In English:

1. images can have many revisions
2. images might become corrupted, as well as revisions
3. only one object will be `final`, i.e. either the image or one of its revisions (an image without revision counts as final)

I would like to get all images from a user that are corrupted.

An image counts as corrupted if any of the following is true:

- the image itself is corrupted and final
- the revision marked as final is corrupted

In the following cases, the image does not count as corrupted:

- the image is final and is not corrupted
- the image has a final revision that is not corrupted

Can this be queried using Django ORM?

Comment: If the `Image` is `final` and not corrupted, can it have a `Revision` that is `final` and corrupt?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no, if the `Image` is `final` it cannot have an `ImageRevision` that is `Final`. Any or all `Image` and `ImageRevision` can be `corrupted` tho.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have an additional issue, if you can help. `ImageRevision`s could be deleted (`deleted=True`). How can I filter them out? Can you expand the accepted answer so that deleted images are never included? Also, this also works when there are no revisions? Thanks!

Comment: @Salvatorelovene: so exactly what is the logic: if a `ImageRevision`/`Image` is `deleted`, then the `corrupt=True` does not count?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem since I'm writing a query to get all corrupted images (by a definition that encompasses corruption of the image itself or the final revision), I want to exclude revisions marked as deleted.

Comment: I think the edited answer should work. Please comment if there are still issues.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thanks for your time! Unfortunately, this doesn't work. For instance, I have an non-corrupted, non-deleted image, that has 3 revisions:

A: non-corrupted, non-deleted, final
B: corrupted, deleted, non-final
C: corrupted, non-deleted, non-final

The query in the accepted returns this image, while for my logic this image is non-corrupted (as the only corrupted revisions are either deleted or non-final).

Comment: the problem is that I can not reproduce this scenario: https://pastebin.com/8NvPX40V perhaps I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem your query works. In my case I accidentally had a revision that was also final. Sorry for wasting too much of your time and thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain these images with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Image.objects.filter(
    Q(final=True, corrupted=True) |
    Q(revisions__final=True, revisions__corrupted=True)
)
```

Note that this will also return images that are final and not corrupted, but have a final revision that is corrupt. Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60683788/django-orm-filter-by-multiple-properties-of-related-object?noredirect=1#comment107365111_60683788), this can never happen.

If I understand the logic behind a `deleted` image/revision correctly, you can filter with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Image.objects.filter(
    Q(final=True, corrupted=True, deleted=False) |
    Q(revisions__final=True, revisions__corrupted=True, revisions__deleted=False)
)
```

This will still include `Images` who are deleted, but with a non-deleted final revision that is corrupt. We can exclude deleted images completely with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Image.objects.filter(
    Q(final=True, corrupted=True) |
    Q(revisions__final=True, revisions__corrupted=True, revisions__deleted=False),
    deleted=False
)
```